# How to have an async endless loop with Promises

Tags: javascript, while-loop, es6-promise

I need to have an "endless" while-loop which has promises inside it. Here's some example code:

```
let noErrorsOccured = true

while (noErrorsOccured){
    someAsyncFunction().then(() => {
        doSomething();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        noErrorsOccured = false;
    });
}

function someAsyncFunction() {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const exampleBool = doSomeCheckup();
            if (exampleBool){
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject("Checkup failed");
            }
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

So this while-loop should run endless, except an error occurs, then the while-loop should stop. How can I achieve this?

I hope you can understand what I mean and thanks in advance.

Comment: Promise reactions (calling fulfilled or rejection handlers) are executed asynchronously after a a thread causing them to be executed has completed. The first while loop is an infinite **blocking** loop, creating an infinite number of promises that never get settled because timeout call backs never occur :D  _Possibly_ you want a timeout or interval timer that that waits 3 seconds after a previous the promise created for an asynchronous check up becomes settled before running another check?

Comment: The problem is that i don't really know how long it takes for my promise to resolve, I only used `setTimeout()` to clarify my example. But Felix Kling's solution works perfectly, so there is no need for an other solution, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

Not with a blocking loop since promises won't be able to settle. You can learn more about [JavaScript's event loop on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Instead, call the function again when the promise is resolved:

```
Promise.resolve().then(function resolver() {
    return someAsyncFunction()
    .then(doSomething)
    .then(resolver);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

Comment: Ah I had messed up at first. Didn't look at the OPs original code close enough

Comment: This code will "eat" the error that occurs, probably fine in this case but BE WEARY of any `.catch((err) =>{})` that doesn't contain a `throw err;`.

Comment: @kingdango: Uh? Are you also weary of any `try { } catch() {}`s where `catch` doesn't rethrow the error? Error handling is the whole point of `catch` clauses...

Comment: Yes, usually.  Most calls on the stack cannot adequately "handle" an exception because the outer calls have dependent consequences.  The only time you should try catch down the stack is when you need to log local scope information that won't be available as the error travels back up the stack, in which case you should log and throw so the outer call has a chance to decide what to do with the exception.

Obviously there are scenarios, batch operations are the best example, where one failed call shouldn't prevent other calls from executing, in which case you "handle the exception" and move on.

Comment: For example, if that code above was in the entry point for a node app, tell me what happens once that console log is written?  Nothing, the process hangs in limbo.  Had you thrown the error the `process.on('unhandledException')` event would be called and since there is no handler it would have terminated the process.

Comment: @kingdango The `catch` shows readers where the error comes out. Readers are expected to extrapolate their error handling needs from that. You're right that this answer works without it, and would mirror the OP's code more closely, since unlike the OP's code it no longer needs `catch` as a loop terminator.

Comment: What are the memory implications of running this forever?

Comment: This answer has a memory leak associated: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6673 You will run out of heap

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (based on discussion here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6673 ) in NodeJS:

```
async function run(){
  // Do some asynchronous stuff here, e.g.
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

(function loop(){
   Promise.resolve()
     .then(async () => await run())
     .catch(e => console.error(e))
     .then(process.nextTick(loop));
})();
```